# Why does in my code json pop dont work? (In python)

Tags: python, json, discord.py, pycord

Let me explain my problem!

I code a Python Discord Bot and it saves the channel id and the owner id!

And if the ticket got closed it need to pop ticket!

My code looks so:

```py
with open("data/tickets.json", "w") as f:
    data.pop(str(ctx.channel.id), f)
```

And the json so:

```json
{
    "channel id 1": {
        "author": 256820568024,
        "claimed": null
    },
    "channel id 2": {
        "author": 43251524366254,
        "claimed": null
}
```

but if i try to close the ticket!
Its delete the complete tickets.json file!
Like there is nothing in it!

But i only want to delete the `channel id 1` section.

And it gives me no error.

Please help me :c

Comment: The snippet of code you posted doesn't actually do anything to modify the file.  You need to read in the existing JSON, delete a key from it or whatever other modifications you want to make, and only *then* write it out again using `json.dumps`.

Comment: can you share the code which defines the variable `data`? at minimum you should provide the complete context (with code) of your issue.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/KidmfXFN

Comment: You're trying to pop with the *index* being a *file descriptor*. Also, you've opened it in (over)write mode, and the file is completely overwritten if you write anything to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your json script is missing a brace. It should be:

```
{
    "channel id 1": {
        "author": 256820568024,
        "claimed": null
    },
    "channel id 2": {
        "author": 43251524366254,
        "claimed": null
    }
}
```

Then, your code is designed to do something different from your original intention. Please, consider the **JSON** Python module. In this way, you will load the json object so that you can manipulate your data as you wish!

```
import json

#read the file
data = json.load(open("data/tickets.json","r"))

#remove the object
del (data[str(ctx.channel.id)])

#if necessary, update the file
with open('data/tickets.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data,file,indent=4)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Its got delete, but its only {} in there (if its only one ticket open)! Without indent :c Edit: but it works i tested it thanks :D